# How to get information of last created files on server

Tags: linux, files

I want to get list of **created files and folders after certain date** in whole server, is it possible and how can i do?

Answer (score 1):

You can't find files based on creation time, but you can find it based on change time, by using `find`

```
find / -ctime -2
```

will list all files and folders changed 2 days or less ago

Comment: ctime does not necessarily reflect creation time.  For example: http://linuxpoison.blogspot.com.ar/2008/03/ctime-atime-and-mtime.html

Comment: I saved the answer too quickly, and went back to edit it while you posted your comment..

Comment: I tested this command and listed large quantity of files i think all isnt created in 2 days.

Comment: The server only gives you change time, not create time. This is the best that can be done.  If you really need a log of change dates, you will need to build a list of what files are there at a given time and then check against it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Linux does not store the file/folder creation date. Have a look at [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_%28Unix%29). You can see the following timestamp kept in inode and retrieved using stat system call.

```
st_atime 
    Time of last access
st_mtime 
    Time of last modification
st_ctime 
    Time of last status change
```